# How to set initial value and auto increment in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, insert, auto-increment

How do I set the initial value for an "id" column in a MySQL table that start from 1001?

I want to do an insert `"INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ('{$name}', '{$email}')";`

Without specifying the initial value for the id column.

Answer (score 671, accepted):

Use this:

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
```

or if you haven't already added an id column, also add it

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ADD INDEX (id);
```

Comment: I realize this was 7 years ago, but... Can I get an explanation of this answer's parts? What does `ADD INDEX` do here? Do I have to add it in the same statement as the `id` column, or can I define the `id` column in the `CREATE TABLE` block and then `ADD INDEX(id)`?

Comment: Heh, time passes by... Sure, define it in CREATE TABLE if you are able to do that. The second "ALTER TABLE" part of answer implies that you have already created a table, and it is probably already deployed somewhere without proper index, which is required for first "ALTER TABLE" to work as intended. I hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Yes, that does help. I was looking at some samples that used these statements in a similar way, and they make more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: The reason for the ADD INDEX is because without it, if you already have a primary key on an existing table, you'll get `there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`. You need the index so it will be a MUL key.

Comment: I tried this on a table that was just created without any rows added yet.  Seems this does not work unless there has been atleast 1 row added to the table first.

Comment: Also if you want to do this on a single line you can use this idiom:
`
    ALTER TABLE users ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
       AUTO_INCREMENT = 1001, 
       ADD INDEX (id);`

Answer (score 78):

### MySQL - Setup an auto-incrementing primary key that starts at 1001:

**Step 1, create your table:**

```
create table penguins(
  my_id       int(16) auto_increment, 
  skipper     varchar(4000),
  PRIMARY KEY (my_id)
)
```

**Step 2, set the start number for auto increment primary key:**

```
ALTER TABLE penguins AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
```

**Step 3, insert some rows:**

```
insert into penguins (skipper) values("We need more power!");
insert into penguins (skipper) values("Time to fire up");
insert into penguins (skipper) values("kowalski's nuclear reactor.");
```

**Step 4, interpret the output:**

```
select * from penguins
```

prints:

```
'1001', 'We need more power!'
'1002', 'Time to fire up'
'1003', 'kowalski\'s nuclear reactor'
```

Comment: How should i do if i want to set a id < 1000 for special penguins?

Comment: You can insert any free id, just put it in the column list: `insert into penguins (my_id, skipper) values(999, "explicit id");` (when using `0` instead of `999` the auto increment value will be inserted)

Answer (score 36):

**MySQL Workbench**

If you want to avoid writing sql, you can also do it in MySQL Workbench by right clicking on the table, choose "Alter Table ..." in the menu.

When the table structure view opens, go to tab "Options" (on the lower bottom of the view), and set "Auto Increment" field to the value of the next autoincrement number.

Don't forget to hit "Apply" when you are done with all changes.

**PhpMyAdmin:**

If you are using phpMyAdmin, you can click on the table in the lefthand navigation, go to the tab "Operations" and under Table Options change the AUTO_INCREMENT value and click OK.

Comment: Are you talking about phpMyAdmin?

Comment: No, I think he's talking about the MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @Saturnian, yes you are right, I meant the Workbench. I will edit my Post to clarify that.

Comment: phpMyAdmin solved an autoincrement issue in one step, I tried going the code route and it wasnt working.

Answer (score 22):

With CREATE TABLE statement

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 100;
```

or with ALTER TABLE statement

```
ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 200;
```

Comment: hint, if you set it to 1 it will default to be just above the highest existing id

Comment: Good point / trick

Answer (score 14):

First you need to add column for auto increment

```
alter table users add column id int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST
```

This query for add column at first. 
Now you have to reset auto increment initial value. So use this query

```
alter table users AUTO_INCREMENT=1001
```

Now your table started with 1001

Answer (score 13):

You could also set it in the `create table` statement.

```
`CREATE TABLE(...) AUTO_INCREMENT=1000`
```

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, If you are too lazy to write the SQL query. Then this solution is for you.
[image]

1. Open **phpMyAdmin**
2. Select desired **Table**
3. Click on **Operations** tab
4. Set your desired initial Value for **AUTO_INCREMENT**
5. Done..!

Answer (score 9):

For this you have to set `AUTO_INCREMENT` value

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = <INITIAL_VALUE>
```

Example

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 101
```

Answer (score 5):

Also , in **PHPMyAdmin** , you can select table from left side(list of tables) then do this by going there. 
**Operations Tab->Table Options->AUTO_INCREMENT.**

Now, Set your values and then press **Go under the Table Options Bo**x.

Answer (score 1):

SET GLOBAL auto_increment_offset=1;

SET GLOBAL auto_increment_increment=5;

auto_increment_increment: interval between successive column values

auto_increment_offset: determines the starting point for the AUTO_INCREMENT column value.
The default value is 1.

[read more here](https://floyk.com/en/post/how-to-change-increment-step-on-auto-increment-fields-in-mysql-1)