# creating a table with a primary key that is auto increment with default values of 10000

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
"CREATE TABLE dummy
(
tnum UNSIGNED INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (tnum),
)";

ALTER TABLE dummy AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

This is not running. I would like to know what causes the error, and alternatives so that I can create an auto-incrementing primary key has a default value of 10000.

Comment: ALTER TABLE dummy tnum DEFAULT = 10000;

Comment: If you mean starting value of auto_increment is 10000. I know your code is the way to do this. What error did you received?

Comment: @ace Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING this is the error i'm getting..

Comment: @Ibu its not working.. thanks for the comment..

Comment: as I have read the posts, I can say that error is generated by php. If the code you've provided is same as the actual code the T_STRING is caused by `ALTER TABLE dummy AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;`. This should be qouted. And you should execute the query one at a time. If you want to execute multi-query try this http://se2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php. And also consider lbu post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set initial value + auto increment in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: The error you are getting is from php. Show us your php code (probably you are missing a semicolon in the line above).

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned is great for AUTO_INCREMENT columns! It gives you twice as many possible values!

Change your query to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
    tnum INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
) AUTO_INCREMENT=10000
```

Comment: Ok, great. And what does this have to do with the OP's problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `unsigned`, the `"` (both the double quotes) and ',' (comma) after `PRIMARY KEY (tnum),`

```
CREATE TABLE dummy
(
tnum INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (tnum)
);

ALTER TABLE dummy AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

It works.

Comment: sorry i edited my code before posting it here.. the comma is simply a typographical error..

Comment: its not working.. the ALTER TABLE DUMMY AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000; is detected to be an error >>> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: I copied and pasted the code from my response and executed it again. It worked fine! Try my new answer, just posted it.

Comment: @lbu: may be, from the mysql code i couldn't guess that, never used php.

Comment: Why remove the `UNSIGNED`?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to set auto_increment start value, you can use this code:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy
(
tnum INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (tnum)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=10000;
```

Comment: the comma (',') after PRIMARY KEY (tnum) should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `dummy` (
  `tnum` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tnum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10000 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

If you are copying and pasting it from somewhere, beware, any special/non-ascii char will result in error

Answer (score 0):

that is because you can't have an auto increment and a default value at the same time, the value will increment for every new entry.

It looks more like you are having a php error to me, show some code in your php file,
The section that is  performing the query is not correct,

Make sure you have matching single quotes or double quotes. and remember yu can only do one query at a time.

use the command line or an application like mysql workbench to create and manipulate your db

Answer (score -1):

Remove `UNSIGNED` from your query.