# how to ensure mysql column has 4 character

Tags: mysql, sql, match, alter-table, zerofill

how to ensure mysql column has 4 character ?

Due to using the MATCH function with minimum 4 char, i want my primary key which is a INT to be at least 4 char.

How can i do it ?

eg. 1 will be 0001 in sql table

Comment: You would have to use a varchar. `0001` as an int will always be `1`

Comment: Start your primary key from 1000?

Comment: @SalmanA What about 1-999?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ZEROFILL** attribute of column. Alter your Primary key column to have zerofill enabled.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `tablename` CHANGE
COLUMN `id` `id` INT(4) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's `LPAD` function:

```
SELECT LPAD('1',4,'0');
    -> '0001'
```

[Docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your primary key is an auto-incremented id.

1. Temporarily take the auto-increment off.
2. Add 999 to every id.  (Of course if other tables use this id as a foreign key, you are going to have to adjust them, too).
3. Re-add the auto-increment, but make sure that it starts at at least 1000.  See: [How to set initial value and auto increment in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: For any production, established relational database this probably isn't feasible.

Comment: @Madbreaks.  You're absolutely right. I'm inferring from the question that it probably is not production stuff.  But if it is, forget what I said.

Comment: That sounds fine.  If it's production data, you don't want to mess with the already existing keys.