# How to assign a AUTO_INCREMENT value in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a **User** migration file in rails project. I want to make my user table id start from 10000. Like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24940715/291240):

```
execute "ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;"
```

After this, I want to set id smaller than 10000. For example, I want to make william's id is 1, how should I do it?

Comment: i doubt it can be done.. did you try creating a record and assigned id manually

Comment: @SRDP It seems work. Actually i tried it. But i made a typo mistake. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this article [link](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-reset-auto-increment,)

> ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = value;
>
> You specify the table name after the ALTER TABLE clause and the value
>   which we want to reset to in the expression AUTO_INCREMENT = value.
>
> Notice that the value must be greater than or equal to the current
>   maximum value of the auto-increment column.

But actually i can create User by assign ":id" property equal smaller then 10000.

```
User.create(:id=>1, :name=>'William')
```

Thanks @SRDP too.

**IMPROTANT:**
You user id may start from 1 if you set :id = 1 first. So set a user from 10000 first, then create any user below 10000.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,but i wont suggest its a good practice .

Create the record first  so it will have some id ie 10067 or something now suppose you want assign thsi record to a id which is not created in your case ie id < 1000 you can do is

```
User.where(id: 1).update_all id: 10067
```