# how set start value for auto increment in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am using my custom auto increment key in my domain class  using

```
 static mapping = { id generator: 'increment', name: 'personId' }
```

Is it possible to start the auto increment from a particular value , say start from 100 ?

Comment: In domain model object's you don't need id field. Or you have some interesting task? And why do you want set particular value for id? Id field must be unique and it doesn't metter 100 or 1000 is first id. I think it depends on your data base.

Comment: Why don't you do this in your custom id generator?

Comment: @alnasfire my problem is i am not providing value while inserting data to this domain.I use  personId as the auto increment value crated by db but , I need it to start from a 3 digit number

Comment: @dev, wich data base do you use?

Comment: @dev, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql

Comment: so , do I need to manually execute the query `ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=100` , or can I set it from domain class

Comment: It will need to be done manually. Well, It will have to be done from the database prompt.

Comment: @AndriyBudzinskyy how do I do it in custom id generator?

Comment: @dev, maybe it will help you http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Setting-IDs-manually-handling-quot-gaps-quot-in-the-ID-series-td4650976.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial value of the autoincrement by using the `org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator` generator. This generator takes the parameter `initial_value`, which will be the the value of your first `id`. (And after that, it will increment by 1, just like you are used to.)

```
static mapping = {
    id(generator: 'org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator', 
        params: [sequence_name: 'start_seq', initial_value: 100])
}
```