# Grails id mapping autoincrement - MySQL

Tags: mysql, grails, hibernate-mapping, auto-increment, grails-domain-class

I have a MySQL table with the ID attribute as autoincremental and I need that, when doing an insert from Grails, the value of the id is auto-completed increasing.

My grails class has the following mapping:

```
static mapping = {
     id column: "id", type: "long", sqlType: "int", generator: 'assigned'
     datasource 'dialer'
     version false
     }
```

But wanting to make an insert gives me the following error:

```
Message: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save ()
```

Would they give me a hand? Thank you!

Comment: grails id auto increments without the mapping definition - try commenting it out and it should just work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281381/how-set-start-value-for-auto-increment-in-grails

Comment: I solved with: id column: "id", type:"long", sqlType: "int", generator: 'increment' ... editing type of generator! increment for assignated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace generator attributes assigned by

identity

which is for mySQL

```
static mapping = {
     id column: "id", type: "long", sqlType: "int", generator: 'identity'
     datasource 'dialer'
     version false
     }
```

[more infomation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator) about hibernate generator(ctrl + F "IDENTITY")

Comment: Can we override this mapping in child class?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is remplace assignated for incremental

id column: "id", type:"long", sqlType: "int", generator: 'increment'