# How to start a new Redmine installation with new issue numbers from a preset number?

Tags: git, sequence, redmine

I lost my Redmine database but retained the repositories which have issue numbers in the git commit messages.

What I want to do is to create a new repo but set the starting number for the issues from an arbitrary number, eg issue 2000.

But I also want to create issues whose number I can set below the starting point, eg 1001 etc, so that I can link them to the commits which are already in the repository logs.

One option I can think of is to prepopulate the database with dummy subjects and descriptions and change the subjects and descriptions afterwards. The other option parse the commit logs for the issue numbers and their notes and enter them as the issues subjects and descriptions.

It is something like this possible and are there some tools are libraries which can help accomplish this?

Comment: Too bad that you lost your original DB. 

I would recommend writing a script that creates issues based upon your git commit messages, that way you will still be able to see relation between issue and committed revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine uses a normal database like mysql so you could set a initial value for the autoincrement within the issue id.

How to change the autoincrement:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485685/4607988

Now I have more time :)
Open the database - hopefully mysql-  and type in this query:

```
ALTER TABLE issues AUTO_INCREMENT=2001;
```

Then your problem should be solved.