# How can I resolve this SQLSTATE error in the context of cakephp 3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have looked through similar posts but they do not seem to apply.

I created a login and registration page on CakePHP 3 and when I tested the registration of a new user.

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.

SQL Query:

INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, created, modified) VALUES (:c0, :c1, :c2, :c3, :c4)
If you want to customize this error message, create src/Template/Error/pdo_error.ctp
```

I have read that it may be due to not having added auto-increment, but when I created id in phpmyAdmin I did check off A.I. for auto increment.

I am also not sure of whether or not it may have to do with my recent additions to my code in UsersController.php:

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;

/**
 * Users Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\UsersTable $Users
 */
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    /**
     * Index method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

        $this->set(compact('users'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }

    /**
     * View method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function view($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Posts']
        ]);

        $this->set('user', $user);
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Add method
     *
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful add, renders view otherwise.
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Edit method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|void Redirects on successful edit, renders view otherwise.
     * @throws \Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function edit($id = null)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
            'contain' => []
        ]);
        if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    /**
     * Delete method
     *
     * @param string|null $id User id.
     * @return \Cake\Network\Response|null Redirects to index.
     * @throws \Cake\Datasource\Exception\RecordNotFoundException When record not found.
     */
    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    // Login Controller
    public function login(){
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if($user){
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'posts']);
            }
            // Bad Login
            $this->Flash->error('Incorrect Login');
        }
    }

    //Logout
    public function logout(){
        $this->Flash->success('You are logged out');
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

    public function register(){
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if($this->request->is('post')){
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
            if($this->Users->save($user)){
                $this->Flash->success('You are registered and can login');
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error('You are not registered');
            }
        }
        $this->set(compact('user'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event){
        $this->Auth->allow(['register']);
    }
}
```

Comment: be sure that your table primary key is auto increment .. (seems not)

Comment: And also truncate it

Comment: scaisEdge, any suggestions on how to ensure this? when I tried to click on A.I. in phpmyAdmin, I get this error: #1067 Invalid Default value for 'id'. My 'id' being the Primary Key.

Comment: scaisEdge, that is exactly what it was. I did not have auto increment as primary key. I guess I did not add it as I was supposed to. I dropped and recreated the table the right way this time and it worked. Please go ahead and post your suggestion as an answer so I can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the framework, it is a simple SQL violation, you need to set the primary key to autoincrement. You can how to set your primary key as autoincrement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql)

If there is still some error that you face, please share.