# My auto increment does not start with 1

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, auto-increment

```sql
 CREATE TABLE DUser (
 [ID]           INT          NOT NULL,  [DUser_Id]  VARCHAR(45) NULL,
 [Name]         VARCHAR (70) NOT NULL,
 [DOB]          DATE         NOT NULL,
 [Password]     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
 [Email]        VARCHAR (70) NOT NULL,
 [Phone_Number] INT          NOT NULL,
 [Gender]       VARCHAR (6)  NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) );


Create TRIGGER DUser_IDColumn    
ON  DUser    
AFTER  INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE duserid SET    
DUser_ID = 'U' + LEFT('0000' + CAST(inserted.ID AS VARCHAR(10)), 5) FROM       DUser duserid

INNER JOIN inserted

ON duserid.ID = inserted.ID

END GO
```

The ID starts at U00000, when I want it to start from U00003, as there are pre-defined values.
PLEASE I NEED HELP!!

[When I Create an user account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2uDr.png)

Comment: The title suggests you expect your autoincrement to start a `1`. The screenshot shows it starting at `0` and in your question you state you want it starting at `3` ... which one is it?

Comment: Also: The Insert trigger is ... well a bit weird. Do you expect `ID` and `DUser_Id` to be in sync? If yes: why bother keeping track of it? If not: What's the problem? Why would you *de-normalize* your database on purpose?

Comment: And a third one, because I just noticed it on the screenshot: **Don't store passwords in your database!**. Store hashes and salts, but **never** the actual password!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set initial value and auto increment in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to reseed your `AUTO-INCREMENT` like below using `ALTER` statement

```sql
ALTER TABLE DUser AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

From your posted code, I don't see that it's a `autoincrement` column at all. Then there is no way you can expect it to start from 1. It's looks like custom identity column.

```sql
CREATE TABLE DUser (
 [ID]           INT          NOT NULL
```

Comment: How do i go about to change it? I want to auto increment the DUser_ID whenever a new one is created. Currently I have two predefined users, U00001, U00002. And when I create, it become U00000 instead of U00003

Comment: @PercyPig, use a `ALTER` statement. Search in stack-overflow ... you will get plenty existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you, in you script where you create the table "DUser" put something like

```
`AUTO_INCREMENT=3`
```

?
So It will be something like

```
CREATE TABLE DUser (
[ID]           INT          NOT NULL,  
[DUser_Id]  VARCHAR(45) NULL,
[Name]         VARCHAR (70) NOT NULL,
[DOB]          DATE         NOT NULL,
[Password]     VARCHAR (30) NOT NULL,
[Email]        VARCHAR (70) NOT NULL,
[Phone_Number] INT          NOT NULL,
[Gender]       VARCHAR (6)  NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC) )
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```