# Reset Wordpress 'next User ID' number

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been setting up a WordPress-based website with a membership system that uses the User ID as a membership number.

During testing I've made many users then deleted them. Now that testing is complete, when I make a new user, they get an ID of 25, 26, 27, etc…

How I can reset the 'next User ID' number back down to 2 (or whatever) so the new users become 2 then 3 then 4 etc.

Is it something I need to do in CPanel in phpMyAdmin / SQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it with phpMyAdmin or SQL.

First go into the **wp_users** table and delete any users you need to.

Then go into the **wp_usermeta** table and delete any meta entries that correspond do the IDs of those deleted users.

Then you need to alter the **wp_users** table to reset its auto increment value. So you can do that in phpMyAdmin, or use SQL like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_users` AUTO_INCREMENT={ID you want to be used next}
```

So if you want the next created user to have the id number 4 it would look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_users` AUTO_INCREMENT=4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to alter `wp_users` with MySQL 5.7.5+ you'll get the following error:

> Invalid default value for 'user_registered'

This is because the `NO_ZERO_DATE` mode was [added as default in MySQL 5.7.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html) which [forbids the date `0000-00-00`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date). WordPress sets the default value for `user_registered` to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, thus this error.

I'm not sure what the best solution is, but because changing user IDs is pretty hacky in the first place this was my quick fix.

I queried the default (session) `sql_mode`:

```
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

(for me on 5.7.28 this was `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`)

I removed `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` and `NO_ZERO_DATE` from this, and then set `sql_mode` to it before altering the table:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode = '(mode string from above without NO_ZERO_DATE)';
ALTER TABLE `wp_users` AUTO_INCREMENT = 2;
```