# How to change default user id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, userid

I want to change default user id and want to set custom id for all user.
For examples  default user id : 1 for 1st person and 2 for 2nd person.

But i want set user id 200 for 1st person,201 for 2nd person.
How can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset Wordpress 'next User ID' number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43162365/reset-wordpress-next-user-id-number)

Answer (score 0):

**ABOUT DB**
is the user id primary key in db, if yes, the first get 200, then set to "auto-increment".

**ABOUT WORDPRESS FILES**
Maybe make a new account for this user which will generate a new database ID. Delete the user with the ID of 1 and attribute all posts / content to the new user you created.