# Cannot set initial value for AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, auto-increment

First, I create column img_ids, which I want to increment later on, with initial value 393.

Next step, I do the following:

```
Alter table img_ids_for_media modify image_id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

This gives me simple incrementation 1,2,3...

After this I try:

```
 Alter table img_ids_for_media  AUTO_INCREMENT = 393
```

This query passes, but does not do anything at all. I still have 1,2,3, not

393,393,394

What can I do with this?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that changing the auto_increment value for a table sets the **next** auto_increment value to be used, it does not affect existing values within the field - rightly so.

What you can do is update the existing `auto_increment` values by adding 392 to them (`image_id=image_id+392`).

Then make sure you set the next `auto_increment` value to `max(image_id)+1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is already answered under How to set initial value and auto increment in MySQL?

Check this link

[How to set initial value and auto increment in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql/19311924)

Comment: That's what exactly the OP did and ended up having this question.