# How to make my field values start with 100 in sql?

Tags: php, sql

I want all the values of the first field(custId) of sql table to start with 100 such that the first value is 1001 up to 100n-1.
my sample code is :

```
create table customer(custId int(25) primary key not null auto_increment,);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set initial value and auto increment in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql)

Comment: What happens when you hit your tenth record? Do you expect to use 1010 or 10010? In the first case you can just set your starting value in your sequence; in the second you can probably get away with sticking 100 on the front when you display it (though your use case isn't at all clear).

Comment: i want the 10th value to be 10010

Answer (score 2):

Try with below query

Set the Auto increment value when create the table.

```
create table customer(custId int(25) primary key not null auto_increment,) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
```

Answer (score 1):

Once your create query is executed, alter the auto increment start value to 1000.

```
ALTER TABLE customer AUTO_INCREMENT=1001;
```

So the first record would have custId = 1001