# How to auto increment another column in sql when the primary key is auto incremented?

Tags: php, html, mysql, auto-increment

I have a table to store the customer details. I need to add a new column to give these customers or new customers a unique auto increment ID to identify them and also need the primary key to keep the count of the customers.

I already have primary key AI to display the number of customers. I Googled and learned that only primary key can be auto incremented. So how can I achieve this?

I need the customer ID to be of only number of about 5-10 digits.
Something like this: uid = 232100001.
It should start from one number and auto increment when the primary key is auto incremented.

Comment: "*I already have primary key AI to display the number of customers*" - There is no guarantee that AI will always ensure that the values are continuous; also you may `delete` some of it later creating gaps. So you should really not depend on the `MAX(<primary key>)` to get total count of customers in the table.

Comment: Why not just derive it from the primary key value e.g. `id + 232100000`?

Comment: Don't derive it from the PRIMARY KEY. Just have a table of customers, and a table of activity

Answer (score 0):

I am using `TRIGGER`s to keep track of the count of such things

More infos you can find [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

For example you can create another table with the name `counters` on which with the trigger will update the `registered_users` column when a user is added or deleted.

For the IDs of the users you just make the primary key start from a specific value. An answer for this is given on another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql).