# How to let ID autoincrement start from certain number in Laravel Migration

Tags: laravel, eloquent, database-migration, laravel-migrations

I want to write a Laravel Migration auto increment ID as a primary key. I want to start this ID with a another value rather than 1. How can I do so ?

The migration `up()` function:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't think there's an elegant way to do this. You'll probably need to run a raw db statement via `DB::statement(..)` and use one of the solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a record with id (desired id -1) and then delete it.

If you add a record with id 999, and then delete it, next record will have id 1000. You can also use SQL identity on your database

Comment: so what will be the initial value ?

Comment: if you add a record with id 999, and then delete it, next record will have id 1000. You can also use SQL identity on your database.

Comment: this is not good way.

Answer (score 11):

As of Laravel 8.x, you can now use this in your migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id()->startingValue(1200);
    });
}
```

Source: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-auto-increment

Answer (score 2):

You can use 2 methods

By Statement
`DB::statement("ALTER TABLE your_table_here SET AUTO_INCREMENT = 9999;");`

By inserting row and deleteing it.

```
DB::table('your_table_here ')->insert(['id' => 99999, ... ,'column' => 'value']);
DB::table('your_table_here ')->where('id', 99999)->delete();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

If you want your **first ID** in the table to be for example **10001**.

**If you are using Laravel 8.x**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->from(10001);
        .
        .
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After Creating Migrations Just Go to your Mysql Database and put this query

```
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

Answer (score -3):

try this ?

```
$table->increments('id')->start_from(10000);
```

Comment: that method doesn't exist, not even in Version 6.0 https://laraveldaily.com/set-auto-increment-start-laravel-migrations/