# How can set AUTO_INCREMENT initial value for primary key using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

How can set AUTO_INCREMENT initial value for primary key using [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql)?.

like this [How to set initial value and auto increment in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485668/how-to-set-initial-value-and-auto-increment-in-mysql)

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 10000;
```

#### The issue

I need to create a table with bigint primary key starting at 10000.

**Generated script**

```
CREATE TABLE `Identity.User` (
    `Id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `UniqueId` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `Username` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `NormalizedUsername` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `Password` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `Email` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `NormalizedEmail` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `Phone` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
    `Mobile` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `CreatedAt` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    `Enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `Active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `EmailConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `EmailConfirmationCode` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `EmailConfirmationDeadline` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    `MobileConfirmed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    `MobileConfirmationCode` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
    `MobileConfirmationDeadline` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    `LoginFailCount` int NOT NULL,
    `LockoutUntil` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `P_Identity.User__Id` PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4; -- **AUTO_INCREMENT=10000 need this**
```

**My C# static method for Identity column**

```
public static PropertyBuilder<long> SetIdentity(this PropertyBuilder<long> builder, DatabaseFacade database, int startsAt = 1, int incrementsBy = 1)
{
    switch (database)
    {
        case DatabaseFacade db when db.IsSqlServer():
            SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(builder, startsAt, incrementsBy);
            break;
        case DatabaseFacade db when db.IsNpgsql():
            NpgsqlPropertyBuilderExtensions.HasIdentityOptions(builder, startsAt, incrementsBy);
            break;
        case DatabaseFacade db when db.IsMySql():
            //MySqlPropertyBuilderExtensions;
            break;
        case DatabaseFacade db when db.IsOracle():
            OraclePropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(builder, startsAt, incrementsBy);
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unknown database provider");
    }
    builder.ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    return builder;
}
```

#### Further technical details

MySQL version: 8.x.x
Operating system: Windows
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql version: 5.0.0
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App version: 5.0.0

Comment: I do not see an easy way. You cannot specify identity column in such way. It is more like issue for Pomelo driver, they have to add this possibility for migrations automatically.

Comment: For a working solution, see [How can set AUTO_INCREMENT initial value for primary key? #1460 (Comment)](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1460#issuecomment-869083044). Proper support will be part of 6.0.

Comment: "Joma".Equals("Satancito") thanks @lauxjpn. +10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @lauxjpn([lauxjpn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2618319/lauxjpn))

Original code in [How can set AUTO_INCREMENT initial value for primary key?](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1460#issuecomment-869083044)

### My modified solution.

**Program.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure.Internal;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Metadata.Internal;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Migrations;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Satancito
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Usage", "EF1001:Internal EF Core API usage.", Justification = "<Pending>")]
    public class CustomMySqlAnnotationProvider : MySqlAnnotationProvider
    {
        public const string AutoincrementAnnotation = "Insane:AutoIncrement";

        public CustomMySqlAnnotationProvider(
            RelationalAnnotationProviderDependencies dependencies,
            IMySqlOptions options)
            : base(dependencies, options)
        {
        }

        public override IEnumerable<IAnnotation> For(ITable table)
        {
            var annotations = base.For(table);
            IEntityType entityType = table.EntityTypeMappings.First().EntityType;

            IAnnotation autoIncrement = entityType.FindAnnotation(AutoincrementAnnotation);
            if (autoIncrement is not null)
            {
                annotations = annotations.Append(autoIncrement);
            }

            return annotations;
        }

    }

    public class CustomMySqlMigrationsSqlGenerator : MySqlMigrationsSqlGenerator
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Usage", "EF1001:Internal EF Core API usage.", Justification = "<Pending>")]
        public CustomMySqlMigrationsSqlGenerator(
            MigrationsSqlGeneratorDependencies dependencies,
            IRelationalAnnotationProvider annotationProvider,
            IMySqlOptions options)
            : base(dependencies, annotationProvider, options)
        {
        }


        protected override void Generate(
            CreateTableOperation operation,
            IModel model,
            MigrationCommandListBuilder builder,
            bool terminate = true)
        {
            base.Generate(operation, model, builder, terminate: false);
            var autoIncrementValue = operation[CustomMySqlAnnotationProvider.AutoincrementAnnotation];
            if (autoIncrementValue is not null && (autoIncrementValue.GetType().Equals(typeof(int)) || autoIncrementValue.GetType().Equals(typeof(long))))//Check if annotation exists.
            {
                builder.Append($" AUTO_INCREMENT {autoIncrementValue.ToString()}");
            }

            if (terminate)
            {
                builder.AppendLine(Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.StatementTerminator);
                EndStatement(builder);
            }
        }

        protected override void Generate(
            AlterTableOperation operation,
            IModel model,
            MigrationCommandListBuilder builder)
        {
            base.Generate(operation, model, builder);
            var autoIncrementValue = operation[CustomMySqlAnnotationProvider.AutoincrementAnnotation];

            if (autoIncrementValue is not null && (autoIncrementValue.GetType().Equals(typeof(int)) | autoIncrementValue.GetType().Equals(typeof(long))))
            {
                builder.Append("ALTER TABLE ")
                    .Append(Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.DelimitIdentifier(operation.Name, operation.Schema))
                    .Append(" AUTO_INCREMENT ")
                    .Append(autoIncrementValue.ToString());

                builder.AppendLine(Dependencies.SqlGenerationHelper.StatementTerminator);
                EndStatement(builder);
            }
        }
    }

    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; } = null!; //Using NRT

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                // Register our custom service implementations (and some logging).
                var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkMySql()
                    .AddSingleton<IRelationalAnnotationProvider, CustomMySqlAnnotationProvider>()
                    .AddScoped<IMigrationsSqlGenerator, CustomMySqlMigrationsSqlGenerator>()
                    .AddScoped(
                        _ => LoggerFactory.Create(
                            b => b
                                .AddConsole()
                                .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                    .BuildServiceProvider();

                var connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=Issue1460";
                var serverVersion = ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString);

                optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString, serverVersion)
                    .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider) // <-- use our service provider 
                    .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                    .EnableDetailedErrors();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>(
                entity =>
                {
                    // Add the custom annotation.
                    entity.HasAnnotation(CustomMySqlAnnotationProvider.AutoincrementAnnotation, 10_000);
                });
        }
    }

    public static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            using var context = new Context();

            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            context.Add(
                new IceCream { Name = "Vanilla" });

            context.SaveChanges();

            var iceCream = context.IceCreams.Single();

            Trace.Assert(iceCream.IceCreamId == 10_000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sql generated when create table**

```
CREATE TABLE `IceCreams` (
          `IceCreamId` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `Name` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NULL,
          CONSTRAINT `PK_IceCreams` PRIMARY KEY (`IceCreamId`)
      ) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 AUTO_INCREMENT 10000;
```